# Add multiple hist fit to a figure, without the hist

Tags: matlab, plot, figure

I'm a matlab newbie, and i'd like to superpose some hist fit on a same figure.
I know the function histfit, but unfortunatly i can't get to remove the hist and only keep the curve.
I guess once i'll know how to do that i'll be able to add several curves using "hold on".

Thanx for any answers or advices!

Comment: you might also find KSDENSITY useful: http://www.mathworks.com/access/helpdesk/help/toolbox/stats/ksdensity.html

Answer (score 12):

`h = histfit(...)` returns a vector of handles h, where h(1) is the handle to the histogram and h(2) is the handle to the fitted curve.

use `delete(h(1))` to delete the histogram.

If you didn't assign a handle to the fitted histo, you can retrieve it using `h = get(gca,'Children')`

Comment: With R2012a, I use `delete(h(2))` to delete the histogram.